# React router dom: isActive prop issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Since i have migrated from CRA to Vite, the isActive prop stays `true` on the root path, when switching routes: "/" -> "/projects" (both are active - i only want one active).
E.g.:https://res.cloudinary.com/de65hz2rz/image/upload/v1665669629/misc/react-router-dom_isActive_tjdntw.jpg

Couldn't find any answers of it being vite specific or I just have some issues in the way i set up the routing (Didn't change any code when migrating and it worked while using CRA).

Thanks in advance for any advice!

App.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Particles} from "./components/elements";
import { SharedLayout } from "./components/layouts";
import { Contact, Error, Home, Projects } from "./pages";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Particles />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavLinks.jsx:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { navLinks } from "../../data/links";

const NavLinks = ({ closeSidebar }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="nav-links">
      {navLinks.map((link) => {
        const { text, url } = link;
        return (
          <li key={nanoid()}>
            <NavLink
              to={url}
              onClick={closeSidebar}
              className={({ isActive }) => {
                console.log(isActive);
                return isActive ? "nav-link active" : "nav-link";
              }}>
              {text}
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NavLinks;
```

Navbar.jsx:

```
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
import Wrapper from "../../assets/wrappers/Navbar";
import { useGlobalContext } from "../../context/context";
import { NavLinks } from "../elements";

function Navbar() {
  const { showSidebar, setShowSidebar } = useGlobalContext();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <nav className="nav fade-in">
        <div className="nav-center">
          <div className="nav-header">
            <button
              className="nav-btn"
              onClick={() => setShowSidebar(!showSidebar)}>
              <FaBars />
            </button>
          </div>
          <NavLinks />
        </div>
      </nav>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

links.js

```
export const navLinks = [
  {
    text: "home",
    url: "/",
  },
  {
    text: "projects",
    url: "/projects",
  },
  {
    text: "contact",
    url: "/contact",
  },
];
```

Comment: What happens when you add the "end" prop to your `<NavLinks />` ?

Comment: I did miss that, thanks for the heads up. Working like expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs, you can use:

```
<NavLink to="/" end>Home</NavLink>
```

Please refer official documentation towards the end of the page https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Comment: Thank you, I did miss to check out the NavLink section. Working now :)